# Is anyone working on / has implemented a "two-factor paper wallet"?

Tags: wallet, security, two-factor

[I just created this wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Two-factor_paper_wallet).

I'm coining the term here, I think ... not sure what was it called when discussed on Bitcointalk.

My question is: Has anyone implemented this "2 factor paper wallet"? Is it being worked on?

Comment: xpost to bitcointalk: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=97485.0

Comment: If it later turns out that the keypair generated by the third party is defective, your money is forever lost. You could just as easily create the initial pair yourself as validate it. In any event, it's not really two factor since both factors are the same (something you have).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - a probabilistic verification process: you order 100 key pairs, and test 99 of them. If they're ok, it's very unlikely that the hundredth one (which you'll use for real) is defective.

Comment: Also, you can generate the two keys yourself on N different devices (Android + Windows + Mac + Linux), and test each part separately. The odds that all four systems have Trojans are vastly reduced. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/User:Casascius/Base58Check-encoded_objects_proposal#Proposed_specification_for_a_multi-part_key_using_EC_multiplication

Comment: It's not that hard to make sure your key generation systems aren't trojaned. The hard part is securing your key storage systems. This just seems to make more problems than it solves. Though I suppose maybe somebody has a problem that it solves.